# Bug on some devices with animation using flutter and flame

Tags: android, flutter, animation, flame

Basically, I have a problem in an app I'm creating from a game based on a tutorial I saw, however, my character's animation is buggy on some devices, and on others it's running normal, as follows the viking animations with animation correct in how it appears on some devices:

[image: Right Animation]

and Viking with wrong animation on some devices (more than one viking showing up almost always, with the animation well buggy):

[image: Viking with wrong animation on some devices]

The spritesheet I'm using has 256x144 pixels images for the viking, where the first 29 frames are him running and the rest he's jumping (idle) follow the lines of code that define the viking animation in Flutter:

part of the animations in the viking.dart file:

```
enum VikingAnimationStates {
  Idle,
  Run,
  Kick,
  Hit,
  Sprint,
}


class Viking extends SpriteAnimationGroupComponent<VikingAnimationStates>
    with Hitbox, Collidable, HasGameRef<VikingRun> {
  
  static final _animationMap = {
    VikingAnimationStates.Idle: SpriteAnimationData.sequenced(
      amount: 19,
      stepTime: 0.1,
      textureSize: Vector2.all(256),
      texturePosition: Vector2(7424, -90), //29*256
    ),
    VikingAnimationStates.Run: SpriteAnimationData.sequenced(
      amount: 29,
      stepTime: 0.034,
      textureSize: Vector2.all(256), 
      texturePosition: Vector2(0, -90), 
    ),
    VikingAnimationStates.Kick: SpriteAnimationData.sequenced(
      amount: 4,
      stepTime: 0.1,
      textureSize: Vector2.all(256),
      texturePosition: Vector2(0, -90), 
    ),
    VikingAnimationStates.Hit: SpriteAnimationData.sequenced(
      amount: 3,
      stepTime: 0.1,
      textureSize: Vector2.all(256),
      texturePosition: Vector2(0, -90),
    ),
    VikingAnimationStates.Sprint: SpriteAnimationData.sequenced(
      amount: 7,
      stepTime: 0.1,
      textureSize: Vector2.all(256),
      texturePosition: Vector2(0, -90),
    ),
  };



  Viking(Image image, this.playerData)
      : super.fromFrameData(image, _animationMap);
```

part where i create the viking in the game inside the viking_run.dart file:

```
_viking = Viking(images.fromCache('spritesheet viking 48 frames 256x144.png'),
    playerData);
```

And the versions of android on both devices are the same

Comment: Something is weird with your `texturePosition`s, why do you have `-90` as y?
And what is happening on the idle state, where you say that it has 19 frames, but from the `texturePosition` I assume that it starts in the bottom right corner and should only be one frame?

Comment: Well, the texture position by -90 is to the viking stay on the ground, if i don't put this he stay floating on the screen, the idle state basically is when he jumps, where is located in the same spritesheet of he running, where the firsts 29 frames are composed by he running, and the rest of the frames, until the 48th frame is composed by the "idle" state, that is like the jumping animation for the character, this 19 the amount of frames for this state

Comment: I don't really get what would happen if you set `texturePosition` to something negative, it should be a coordinate within the spritesheet. Try to remove it (`Vector2(0, 0)`) is default. And then try to set the `position` of the viking instead. You can join our discord if you want realtime help. https://discord.com/invite/pxrBmy4

Comment: Well,I entered your discord, I tried to change the texturePosition like you said to 0 in all the animations, but the issue stay happening on some devices, of the animation beeing bugged this problem is very strange, i am weeks trying to figure out but I can't understand really why this is happening

Comment: Write something in the Flame channel and I'll help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that your sprites are 256x144 in the sprite sheet, but you use `textureSize: Vector2.all(256)`. Try changing that to `Vector2(256, 144)` instead.

Also the `texturePosition` should never be anything negative, it defines a position in the sprite sheet. Since you only have one row of sprites in your sprite sheet you should always have y as `0` and then you can change x for where the sequence of each animation should start.